# Does Session in Hibernate save data to memory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

when i use Hibernate, does Session which created by SessionFactory will save all data from Transaction to memory ?

Comment: Do you ask about Hibernate Caching?

Comment: No, i dont think it relevant with hibernate cache

Comment: I think you might need to call the `save()` method for it to save. The docs say that `save() and persist() result in an SQL INSERT, delete() in an SQL DELETE and update() or merge() in an SQL UPDATE` ([link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html)). Btw here is a fantastic [resource](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.